# Помогите с доработкой кода ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Приветствую Уважаемые!
Имеется такой вот не хитрый функционал:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код этого функционала:

```
<section  class="col col-6">
<label class="toggle">
<input name="monetizationType" value="rebill" <? if($row['monetizationType'] === "rebill"){ echo "checked='checked'"; } ?>  type="radio">
<i data-swchon-text="ВКЛ" data-swchoff-text="ВЫКЛ"></i><h5 id="rebill" class="text-left text-<? if($row['monetizationType'] === "rebill"){ echo "success"; } else { echo "danger"; } ?>"><strong>Ребиллы</strong></h5></label>
<label class="toggle">
<input name="monetizationType" value="autosell" <? if($row['monetizationType'] === "autosell"){ echo "checked='checked'"; } ?>  type="radio">
<i data-swchon-text="ВКЛ" data-swchoff-text="ВЫКЛ"></i><h5 id="autosell" class="text-left text-<? if($row['monetizationType'] === "autosell"){ echo "success"; } else { echo "danger"; } ?>"><strong>Автовыкуп</strong></h5></label>
<label class="toggle">
<input name="monetizationType" value="credit" <? if($row['monetizationType'] === "credit"){ echo "checked='checked'"; } if($row['creditMode'] === "off"){ echo "class='form-control' disabled='disabled'"; }?> type="radio">
<i data-swchon-text="ВКЛ" data-swchoff-text="ВЫКЛ"></i><h5 id="credit" class="text-left text-<? if($row['monetizationType'] === "credit"){ echo "success"; } else { echo "danger"; } ?>"><strong>Кредитование</strong></h5></label>
</section>
```

код обработки этих данных:

```
$("#smart-mod-eg1").click(function(e) {
            $.SmartMessageBox({
                title : "Изменение настроек",
                content : "Вы действительно хотите изменить настройки аккаунта?",
                buttons : '[НЕТ][ДА]'
            }, function(ButtonPressed) {
                if (ButtonPressed === "ДА") {
        
 
          var msg   = $('#settingsUpd').serialize();
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
               url: '<?php echo ASSETS_URL; ?>/php/settings.php',
              data: msg,
                        success: function(data) {
            $('#error').html(data);
          },
              error:  function(xhr, str){
            alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode + '. Разработчики уже в курсе...');
              }
            });
     
                    $.smallBox({
                        title : "Выполнено",
                        content : "<i class='fa fa-cog'></i> <i>Настройки изменены</i>",
                        color : "#659265",
                        iconSmall : "fa fa-check fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
                        timeout : 5000
                    });
                    
                    $('#rebill').removeClass('text-left text-danger');
                    $('#rebill').addClass('text-left text-success');
                }
                if (ButtonPressed === "НЕТ") {
                    $.smallBox({
                        title : "Не выполнено",
                        content : "<i class='fa fa-cog'></i> <i>Вы отказались от изменения настроек</i>",
                        color : "#C46A69",
                        iconSmall : "fa fa-times fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
                        timeout : 5000
                    });
                }

            });
            e.preventDefault();
        })
```

так вот, в этом куске кода обработчика:

```
$('#rebill').removeClass('text-left text-danger');
$('#rebill').addClass('text-left text-success');
```

удаляется класс, который выделяет красным и добавляется класс, который выделает зеленым текст. Но в данном варианте он делает это только с  id=rebill.
Как правильно сформировать код, чтобы было с условием - если id=rebill в режиме ON, т.е. выбран то делаем то-то, если id=autosell то делаем то-то и т.д.?
Т.е. у меня без перезагрузки изменяются настройки и нужно чтобы без перезагрузки было соответствующее выделение текста цветом.

Благодарю за внимание!